# Fill fields depending on a select

Tags: php, select, field

Very good days.

I am having difficulties to fill some "input" fields depending on what is selected in a select field.

[image]

I think it should be in Ajax, because I want the RUT, Telephone, Address and eMAil fields to be updated depending on what is selected in the Select Company.

Now, i'ḿ trying with php. I am using PDO and MVC.

In my model I have:

```
public function TraerEmpresas()
{
    try
    {
        $result = array();

        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas");
        $stm->execute();

        return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

In my view, i have:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <label  for="floatingName">Empresa</label>
        <select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-select" style="height:80px;" placeholder="Empresa">
            <option value = ""></option>
<?php 
foreach($this->model->TraerEmpresas() as $r): 
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $r->razonsocial; ?>"><?php echo $r->razonsocial; ?></option>
<?php 
endforeach; 
?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" name="rut_dest" value="<?php echo $r->rut; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="RUT" required>
        <label for="floatingName">RUT</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" name="tel_emp_dest" value="<?php echo $r->telefono; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Teléfono</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" name="direccion_dest" value="<?php echo $r->direccion; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Dirección</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" name="mail_emp_dest" value="<?php echo $r->email; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="eMail" required>
        <label for="floatingName">eMail</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is not working.

Can someone give me a hand?

What is expected is that: by selecting an option from a select field, other attached fields update their content.

Comment: "Is not working." - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Where's the code that filters any database result?

Comment: The way I have it already loads the data of the last company, even if I don't choose any option from the select.
In case of choosing any option from Select, it does not update the mentioned fields.

Comment: You need to prompt an "onChange()" function with your select element.
This function should then edit your other form fields the way you intend them to look.
Since you didn't specify what is the change you want, I can't really go into details

Comment: @tola What I need is that when choosing a company name from the select field, it load the other company data in the other fields (rut, address, telephone, email)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your clarification in the comments, I believe this is what you are trying to get:

- First, you need to add an `onChange()` prompt to your `<select>` element. (The function itself is seen below)
- Second, you need to add and id to all your text elements.

You should remove all the echoes in the text elements. They don't work anyways - PHP only loads data once, when the page is loaded. Any dynamic changes to the page later can only be achieved with JS.

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <label  for="floatingName">Empresa</label>
        <select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-select" style="height:80px;" placeholder="Empresa" onChange="changeDetails(this.value)">
            <option value = ""></option>
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach($this->model->TraerEmpresas() as $r): 
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i++; ?>"><?php echo $r->razonsocial; ?></option> // if you have a serial id, you can use it instead of the $i
<?php 
endforeach; 
?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="name="rut_text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="RUT" required>
        <label for="floatingName">RUT</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="tel_text" name="tel_emp_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Teléfono</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="dir_text" name="direccion_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Dirección</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="mail_text" name="mail_emp_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="eMail" required>
        <label for="floatingName">eMail</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Lastly, you need to add the function.

**NOTE**: this function MUST be in a script tag at the end of your page (after `</body>`), because it uses data you pull on the `<select>` line.

```
    function changeDetails(value){
        options = <?= json_encode($options) ?>;
        document.getElementById("rut_text").value = options[value-1]['rut'];
        document.getElementById("tel_text").value = options[value-1]['telefono'];
        document.getElementById("dir_text").value = options[value-1]['direccion'];
        document.getElementById("mail_text").value = options[value-1]['email'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <label  for="floatingName">Empresa</label>
    <select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-select" style="height:80px;" placeholder="Empresa" onChange="cambiarDatos(this.value)">
        <option value = ""></option>
        <?php 
            $i = 1;
            foreach($this->model->TraerEmpresas() as $r): 
        ?>
        <option data-rut="<?php echo $r->rut; ?>" data-telefono="<?php echo $r->telefono; ?>" data-direccion="<?php echo $r->direccion; ?>" data-email="<?php echo $r->correodt; ?>" value="<?php echo $i++; ?>"><?php echo $r->razonsocial; ?></option> 
        <?php 
            endforeach; 
        ?>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
       <input type="text" id="rut_dest" name="rut_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="RUT" required>
        <label for="floatingName">RUT</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="tel_emp_dest" name="tel_emp_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Teléfono</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="direccion_dest" name="direccion_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección" required>
        <label for="floatingName">Dirección</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" id="mail_emp_dest" name="mail_emp_dest" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="eMail" required>
        <label for="floatingName">eMail</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
<script>


(function (d,w) {


    document.getElementById("empresa").addEventListener("change", el => {

        let option = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset;

        d.getElementById("rut_dest").value = option.rut;
        d.getElementById("tel_emp_dest").value = option.telefono;
        d.getElementById("direccion_dest").value = option.direccion;
        d.getElementById("mail_emp_dest").value = option.correodt;

    })

})(document, window)
```

Thanks to all!